# I'm trying to pass a value by href to a php page to retrieve the rest of the data from that row of a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, href

I'm trying to pass a value by href to PHP to return the rest of the data in that row of my mysql database table.

```
so  when I click on  <a href="datainflux.php?id=id_num>Details</a>

 I want it to send the id number (id=id_num) to datainflux.php to return the 'item', 'ranking', 'descript' and 'type' that use
```

that ID number. I'm pretty sure both the href and the php are flawed.

```
This is the PHP code I'm using

<?php
$hostname="localhost"; //local server name default localhost
$username="root";  //mysql username default is root.
$password="";       //blank if no password is set for mysql.
$database="spkwi312_Organic";  //database name which you created
$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
  if(! $con)
    {
      die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database,$con);


$id_num = id_num

$query = sprintf("SELECT item, ranking, descript, type FROM og4real 
   WHERE id_num='%s'",
   mysql_real_escape_string($id_num));

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
   $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
   $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
   die($message);
  }

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['item'];
  echo $row['ranking'];
  echo $row['descript'];
  echo $row['type'];

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: change $id_num = id_num to $id_num = $_GET['id_num']; and pass like <a href="test.php?id_num=5">2</a>

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon `$id_num = id_num` - **IF** (*the big IF*) that's part of your working code, it will break it. Using proper error reporting methods, would have signaled that.

Comment: What is your question? what errors do you have? see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

change :

```
$id_num = id_num;
```

to

```
$id_num = $_GET['id_num'];
```

and the link on the previous page should be :

```
<a href="datainflux.php?id_num=value">Details</a>
```

**PS :**  `value` should be replaced by the real `ID_NUM`

Comment: Change `$id_num = id_num;`? to .... ok (will +1), but who says that `$id_num = id_num` isn't part of OP's actual code? Let's see if OP will pick up on [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183980/im-trying-to-pass-a-value-by-href-to-a-php-page-to-retrieve-the-rest-of-the-dat#comment39213791_25183980). Maybe it is in there, but for face value, OP's code will break at that line.

Answer (score 0):

try this , you forget to use "data": right after

```
dataSource: {
            "chart": {
            "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
            "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
            "xAxisName": "Month",
            "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
            "theme": "zune"
            },
```

copy below code .

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>My first chart using FusionCharts Suite XT</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: "column2d",
        renderAt: "chartContainer",
        width: "500",
        height: "300",
        dataFormat: "json",
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
            "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
            "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
            "xAxisName": "Month",
            "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
            "theme": "zune"
            },
            "data": <?php
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234") or die("Error Connect to Database");
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("customer");
    $strSQL = "SELECT CustomerID, Budget FROM customer";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");

    $json = array();

    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){

    $json[] = $r;

    }

    //Display the JSON data
    echo $json_data=json_encode($json); 

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    ?>
        }
        }
    });
    revenueChart.render("chartContainer");
});  


        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```